# odd row.names columns appear in reshape

Tags: r, reshape

I think I am so close to the solution, I just need a few pointers in the right direction and I would very much appreciate straightening this out!

So I have a dataset that I want to turn into only two columns. Here is a similar dummy dataset.

```
1   1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
2   2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4
3   3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4
4   4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4
```

It is a csv, so when I import it R attaches its own headers, like so:

```
V1  V2   V3   V4   V5
1   1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4
2   2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4
3   3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4
4   4.1  4.2  4.3  4.4
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
id value
1  1.1
1  1.2
1  1.3
1  1.4
2  2.1
2  2.2
...
4  4.4
```

The problem is, this is an ongoing project and there will be more columns to the dataset (V6, V7, etc) so I can't hard-code anything. I have a list saved of all the heading names, and this appears to work.

```
data <- read.csv(file="location", header = FALSE)
dates = ncol(data)
list = 2:dates
variables <-paste0('V',list)
```

so now variables is a list of the column names for all of the columns that I want to condense into one.

My code for reshaping is this:

```
newdata <- reshape(data, idvar = "V1", direction = "long", varying = variables, sep="")
```

but it gives me an unexpected data frame as a result. I get:

```
row.names   V1  time      V
      1.2    1     2    1.1
      2.2    2     2    2.1
      3.2    3     2    3.1
      4.2    4     2    4.1
      1.3    1     3    1.2
      ...
```

The V1 and V columns are correct - it's what I want and it's matched up correctly, if not sorted. However, where did row.names and time come from? I can delete time but not row.names because when I try to access the column row.names with newdata[,1] it gives me the V1 column, and newdata["row.names"] says "undefined columns selected."

So if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong or how to reformat my reshape statement so these weird columns do not appear I would be very grateful. Thank you!

Comment: do you need to keep it in base? I'd use `reshape2::melt(data, id.vars = 'V1')`

Comment: melt won't install :(

Comment: the package is reshape2, the function is melt

Comment: @rawr, that's avoiding the question rather than trying to answer it.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I was dealing with something similar two weeks ago. `base::reshape` is so painful and `reshape::cast/reshape2::melt` are such a joy to use that it is sensible to avoid incurring the pain in the first place.

Comment: @smci, There are times when each shine. To be honest, I've never found base R's `reshape` that painful....

Answer (score 4):

### The behavior you describe...

First, the behavior you describe is from using `View` or `fix`, where if there are `row.names` that are not just a sequence of the number of rows in the dataset, in the spreadsheet view, it shows as another column of data named "row.names".

Here's a small example:

```
## Sample data
df1 <- df2 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, 
                                dimnames = list(c("A", "B"), c("a", "b"))))
rownames(df2) <- NULL

fix(df1)  # R's spreadsheet view
```

[image]

```
View(df1) # RStudio data viewer
```

[image]

```
fix(df2)
```

[image]

```
View(df2)
```

[image]

### Getting `reshape` to work as you expect

Second, the `reshape` function in base R has a `new.row.names` argument. Unfortunately, you can't simply set that to `NULL`. You need to set it to a sequential vector if you want to get rid of the strange `row.names` that are created by default. To do that, you need to know how long your final data will be (the product of the number of varying columns by the number of rows in the original dataset). As such, you can do something like:

```
id <- "V1"
varCols <- setdiff(names(mydf), "V1")
out <- reshape(mydf, direction = "long", idvar=id, varying=varCols, sep = "", 
               new.row.names=sequence(prod(length(varCols), nrow(mydf))))
```

This still leaves the `time` variable, so you need to manually remove that like:

```
out$time <- NULL
out
#    V1   V
# 1   1 1.1
# 2   2 2.1
# 3   3 3.1
# 4   4 4.1
# <:::SNIP:::>
# 12  4 4.3
# 13  1 1.4
# 14  2 2.4
# 15  3 3.4
# 16  4 4.4
```

Alternatively, you can do what you did, then set `row.names(out) <- NULL` instead of using the `new.row.names` argument from `reshape`.

### Other approaches

In base R, another approach is to use `stack` and just drop the "ind" column (which is the first column in the stacked data). Then, just bind that back in with the "id" column.

```
cbind(mydf[1], stack(mydf[-1])[1])
#    V1 values
# 1   1    1.1
# 2   2    2.1
# 3   3    3.1
# 4   4    4.1
# <:::SNIP:::>
# 12  4    4.3
# 13  1    1.4
# 14  2    2.4
# 15  3    3.4
# 16  4    4.4
```

Alternatively, as has already been mentioned in comments, use `melt` from "reshape2":

```
install.packages("reshape2") ## if it is not yet installed
library(reshape2)
out2 <- melt(mydf, id.vars="V1")
out2$variable <- NULL
out2
#    V1 value
# 1   1   1.1
# 2   2   2.1
# 3   3   3.1
# 4   4   4.1
# <:::SNIP:::>
# 12  4   4.3
# 13  1   1.4
# 14  2   2.4
# 15  3   3.4
# 16  4   4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a data frame, you can do it through reshape 2 easily with `melt()`. Something like:

```
newdata <- melt(data, measure.vars = 1:ncol(data))
```

This'll give you a data frame of "Variable" (containing each column name) and "value" (containing the values attached to each column name).

If you want to orient the dataframe around V1, you probably want `melt(data, id.vars = 1, measure.vars = 2:ncol(data))` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, but  unfortunately I can't get reshape to install. Unfortunately, when I try, it gives the message: Loading required package: reshape
Loading required package: plyr
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Comment: Again, it's [reshape2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/index.html), not reshape. The error message is fairly self-explanatory; you also need the dependencies (namely plyr, and Rcpp). If you're installing directly from CRAN you should be able to automatically retrieve the dependencies.

Comment: @Ironholds, not one of your better answers. Your first sentence mentions `melt` from "reshape2", but all of your examples are from base R's `reshape` function. I would find this answer very confusing if I didn't already know something about reshaping data.

Comment: *shakes head*; yeah, my mistake. Got distracted. Thanks for pointing it out (in the future, you can do so via an edit of course ;)).

Comment: @user3552980: now corrected. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Ironholds, Based on the answer you had, I didn't know what my edit should be :-)